# Optical interferometers resolution

Tags: observational-astronomy, interferometry, imaging

I found this interesting list of optical interferometers:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_astronomical_interferometers_at_visible_and_infrared_wavelengths

But I can't understand which is the smallest size of a visible object in Earth orbit (let's suppose 300 km high).
Or at least it would be enough to know the resolution in radiants or degrees.

Answer (score 2):

The angular resolution of an interferometer is approximately given by:

$$ \theta = \frac{\lambda}{d} $$

where $\lambda$ is the wavelength used and $d$ is the baseline. The table in the article you link doesn't give the angular resolution directly. It does give the baseline, but is vague about the wavelengths used. I think you will have to Google the details on each interferometer to calculate the resolution.

For example the Keck interferometer has a baseline of 85m and observes at 2.2$\mu$m and 10$\mu$m. If we use the formula above we calculate the 10$\mu$m resolution to be $1.16 \times 10^{-7}$ radians, while the [actual resolution is 24 milliarcseconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._M._Keck_Observatory#Instruments) or $1.18 \times 10^{-7}$ radians. The close agreement is somewhat fortuitous - you should regard the equation as an order of magnitude estimate.

The relationship between the resolution, wavelength and baseline is a result of calculating the diffraction from a circular aperture. The pattern formed is called an [Airy disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk).

Comment: This would mean that diameters of single telescopes do not matter. So I could just place two 10mm telescopes 10 km apart to get astonishing resolution.

Comment: @jumpjack: in principle yes, but a receiving area of $2 \times \pi(5mm)^2$ wouldn't pick up much signal so you wouldn't be able to detect weak sources. You want a trade off between as large a receiving area as possible and as big a baseline as possible.

Comment: So how could the formula be completed to take into account target brightness?

Comment: @jumpjack: I'm not sure what you're asking. The resolution doesn't depend on the brightness, or at least the diffraction limit doesn't, except I suppose that you need a minimum number of photons to get a decent image.

Comment: How many pixels per meter will be in an image of a target T km away shot by an interferometer made of telescopes with diameter D mm and  F km far away one from the other?